# How to parse this in julia?

Tags: parsing, julia

```
julia> a= readline("/root/rock.txt")
"\x01\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x02\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x03\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x04\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x05\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x06\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

rock here is just a random file containing some random text.

```
julia> pointexp =parse(a)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching parse(::String)
Closest candidates are:
  parse(::Type{T<:Integer}, ::AbstractChar; base) where T<:Integer at parse.jl:41
  parse(::Type{T<:Integer}, ::AbstractString; base) where T<:Integer at parse.jl:240
  parse(::Type{T<:Real}, ::AbstractString; kwargs...) where T<:Real at parse.jl:378
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at REPL[6]:1
```

Comment: What do you want to parse it as?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you want to get raw bytes of your `String` for later processing. This can be obtained by passing the `String` to a `Vector{UInt8}()` constructor - see the example below:

```
julia> some_text = "\x01\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x02\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x03\0\0\0";                        

julia> Vector{UInt8}(some_text)                                        
20-element Array{UInt8,1}:                                             
 0x01                                                                  
 0x00                                                                  
 0x00                                                                  
 0x00                                                                  
 0x00                                                                                                                              
    ⋮                                                                                                                                   
 0x00                                                                  
 0x03                                                                  
 0x00                                                                  
 0x00                                                                  
 0x00
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to represent each character as an integer, you may do

```
julia> s = "\x01\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x02\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x03\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x04\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x05\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x06\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\a\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

julia> [Int(c) for c in s]
72-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 0
 0
 0
...
```

`Int` can of course be replaced for any other Integer type.

Comment: It would make more sense to do `[Int(c) for c in s]`, otherwise you needlessly create an extra array.